# jsdoc fields not parsed

Tags: javascript, field, documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Why are my fields getting ignored by jsdoc?

```
/**
* Matrix object for operations on matrices
* @constructor
* @param {number[][]} m - values
* @param {number} def - default size def x def
*/
function Matrix(m, def){

/**
number[][] - values
*/
this.m;

/** 
 * number - number of rows 
 */
this.rows;

/**
 * number - number of cols
 */
this.cols;



if(m != null){
    this.m = m;
    this.rows = m[0].length;
    this.cols = m.length;
}
else {
    this.m = new Array(def);
    for (var i = 0; i < def; i++) {
        this.m[i] = new Array(def);
    }
    this.rows = def;
    this.cols = def;
    this.initI();
}
}

/**
 * initializes the Matrix as Ident-Matrix
 */
Matrix.prototype.initI = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.rows; i++){
       for(var j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
            if(i == j) this.m[i][j] = 1;
            else this.m[i][j] = 0;
       }
   }
}
```

The object with its function normally gets parsed, however the fields
`m`, `rows`, and `cols` are getting ignored by jsdoc.

In another code where I don't use the `prototype` syntax its normally parsing.
edited the numbers

Comment: `double` and `int` are not javascript types, use `number` instead.

Comment: i changed everything to number but it still dont find it

Answer (score 0):

i just saw that you have to assign a value to the field so jsdoc parse it